# Should we merge back into back-button?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms, retag-request

There are now 186 questions tagged [back](/questions/tagged/back), and 215 tagged [back-button](/questions/tagged/back-button). The latter has the synonyms [backbutton](/questions/tagged/backbutton) and [browser-back-button](/questions/tagged/browser-back-button), too. None of them have tag wikis or excerpts.

**All** the questions tagged [back](/questions/tagged/back) also have the word button in it (at least the search [`[back] -button`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bback%5D+-button) gives 0 results), which seems to indicate that they really all are about a back button of some kind.

Thus I propose merging [back](/questions/tagged/back) into [back-button](/questions/tagged/back-button), and declaring it a synonym.